# Base64 Decode not complete

Tags: go, base64

I have bee trying to decode some string returned from other system, but the decoded string have different result if i decode with online decoder or using PHP. I've been trying using `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString()` and `base64.StdEncoding.Decode()` but the result still not the same as the result of online decoder or PHP code.

Here is my code:

```
// encoded string
s := "HxJVICMcHCYeHUJcEWISWk09JgxHBwRPXHlHWFoGf1JXCkgFS1xXVU9Ze1FSCUwUIFMdGx0-SglVDmRNUHdAJRETRR0hHx0aIB1OExcgUCkeRyEaDUE5Y1oTREhcCRJSXAtWHBwfJSUYFUALUFd-VlkIU0JYFg5TA04PURA_OFBQXHpXWVxTSEZlC1FZTH4TKTUXGx1ORBcfSB0fO0xRJRoRVxsmExcoIhxEAxsQfF9bD1tXSQd-XEkBShEoPH80UWEJWAhAQhA0XgNVTwdWZxEX"

// add '=' on the right string
strHelper := string2.NewStringHelper()
sl := math.Ceil(float64(len(s) / 4 * 4))
sp := strHelper.StrPadRight(s, "=", int(sl))
sp = strtr(sp, map[string]string{"-_": "+/"})
  
// decode the string using base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString()
spb, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(sp)
  
// decode the string using base64.StdEncoding.Decode()
b64 := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.DecodedLen(len(sp)))
n, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(b64, []byte(sp))

// decode the string using base64.NewDecoder()
b64s := strings.NewReader(sp)
b64d := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, b64s)
buf := new(strings.Builder)
io.Copy(buf, b64d)

// result of decoded string
U #&B\bZM=&GO\yGXZRW
HK\WUOY{QR L S

// result from online decoder or PHP
U #&B\bZM=&GO\yGXZRW
HK\WUOY{QR L S>J   UdMPw@%E! N P)G!
A9cZDH\    R\V%%@PW~VYSBXSNQ?8PP\zWY\SHFeQYL~)5NDH;LQ%W&("D|_[[WI~\IJ(<4Qa    X@B4^UOVg
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Yqf2I2QgWxS

Please can someone enlightened me where my code is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never omit errors in Go! If you check it:

```
data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output:

```
panic: illegal base64 data at input byte 71
```

Your input is constructed not from the standard Base64 charset. The standard charset uses the `+` and `/` characters. Your input is constructed using a modified charset, a charset safe and used to transmit encoded values in URLs which uses `-` and `_`.

So decode using [`base64.URLEncoding`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64#URLEncoding):

```
data, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(data))
```

This will not result in an error (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/TB6sbHGjZZr)).

If your input does not contain the padding characters, then use [`base64.RawURLEncoding`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64#RawURLEncoding).

Comment: thank you, it seems i've been using the wrong encoding technique